# How to make the interface for a camera app on the IPhone different than the IPad for the same app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, camera, resize

The reason I am asking this question is because the IPad's entire screen in portrait mode has a ratio of 3:4 and the portrait mode of the Iphone's ratio is 16:9. However the standard camera size of both devices is 3:4. So the camera covers the entire Ipad screen such as in the [standard Apple IPad camera interface](https://www.imore.com/sites/imore.com/files/styles/large/public/field/image/2013/11/retina_ipad_mini_camera_hero_fixed.jpg?itok=xR1y7u5n). But is 3:4 on a 16:9 screen leaving edges on the Iphone such as the [standard Apple IPhone camera interface](https://www.imore.com/sites/imore.com/files/styles/larger_wm_brw/public/field/image/2016/03/iphone-se-macro-11.jpg?itok=K4kbWMtS). How have other developers such as Camera+ solved this problem? Did they create two different interfaces on the same IOS Deployment Project or did they create two different projects(one for IPad, one for IPhone)? Any recommendations would be very appreciated. Which option would be less of a hassle?